# Ellipsis in struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have searched this a lot and have found nothing, everything is ellipsis in function arguments, so this brings me too: Is it possible to use an ellipsis in a struct like this?:

```
struct foo
{
   ...
}
```

And how would I go about using this?

Comment: The question is: **Why do you need that?**, or **what behaviour expect from that?**

Comment: Knowing what you know about the purpose of ellipses in function parameters, what exactly is it you think it would do in a `struct`'s definition? If you describe what you're trying to do, perhaps someone can suggest an alternative way.

Comment: Actually, what I was going to use it for is to make my own programming language and use this to make my own kind of "function". Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: @retsgorf297 It's still not clear what you mean, however you may want to take a look at [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).

Comment: Oh, let me try: So you are looking for a data structure (A plain struct in this case) to hold the parsing data of your variadic functions?

Comment: Not much information to go by, but are you looking for something like a functor, essentially enabling you encapsulate varying functionality inside a homogenous interface?

Comment: Well, this is the only was I could think of to do this.  I thought I would name the struct "func" and when it is created the user would declare class, etc. in it that would do something to make it somewhat like a function

Comment: Why do you want to waste your time creating a new language?  Creating a compiler for a new language takes years by large teams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it isn't. This must come from some example in text, but it isn't valid code.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.  Actually, what I was going to use it for is to make my own programming language and use this to make my own kind of "function".  Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: @retsgorf297: If you have a question that's not the same as this question, please make a new post. Be sure to check the FAQ first, though, for whether the question is appropriate.

Comment: sorry, i'm still a little new to this